# how to check and replace list element in dictionary key using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to check if list element are exist in dictionary key then replace list element with dictionary values.

**Input Data**

```
list1 : ['Customer_Number', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name']
dict1 : {'Customer_Number': 'A', 'First_Name': 'B', 'Middle_Name': 'C', 'Last_Name': 'D', 'Org_Names': 'E'}
```

**Expected Output**

```
list: ['A', 'B', 'D']
```

**code tried**

```
for ele in list1:
    if ele in dict1.keys():
        list1.append(dict1.values())
```

**Error getting**

```
keys: dict_keys(['Customer_Number', 'First_Name', 'Middle_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Org_Names'])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict_keys'
```

Comment: I suggest you replacing `:` with `=` such as:
    `list1 = ['Customer_Number', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name']
    dict1 = {'Customer_Number': 'A', 'First_Name': 'B', 'Middle_Name': 'C', 'Last_Name': 'D', 'Org_Names': 'E'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting errors because you are trying to use a list as a key of the dictionary, which is not possible as
only immutable objects like **strings**, **tuples**, and **integers** can be used as a key in a dictionary. To solve this error, make sure that you only use hashable objects when creating an item in a dictionary.

Now moving towards what you want to implement

```
list1 = ['Customer_Number', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name']
dict1 = {'Customer_Number': 'A', 'First_Name': 'B', 'Middle_Name': 'C', 'Last_Name': 'D', 'Org_Names': 'E'}
newList = []
for key, value in dict1.items():
if key in list1:
    newList.append(value)
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
list1 = ['Customer_Number', 'First_Name', 'Last_Name']
dict1 = {'Customer_Number': 'A', 'First_Name': 'B', 'Middle_Name': 'C', 'Last_Name': 'D', 'Org_Names': 'E'}

res = [v for k,v in dict1.items() if k in list1]

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
res = list()
for k, v in dict1.items():
    if k in list1:
        res.append(v)

print(res)
```